# The line chart draws additional Y values

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2, chartjs-2.6.0

My values are ranging from 0 to -6000... However, chart.js line chart is drawing the y-axis starting from 0 down up to -25000...  The lines therefore almost overlap each other.  How can I prevent the y-axis from drawing those excess values so my chart will look bigger.

Config is as follows:

```
type: 'line',
data: {
    labels: ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Sample',
            data: [0, -2000, -1500, -1300, -4000, -4800, -4950]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can show the code?

Comment: I edited, it's just a simple dataset

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Chart.js, 2.7.2? Significant changes/fixes to the scale code are included in recent releases.

Comment: yes, i am using the latest

Comment: It [works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haPal.png). Please update your question with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: let me try if i can provide.  cause the code to achieve it is so complex, that's why I just give the expected config after the code runs.